# unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate service and controller error

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type '.EMSWebapi.IUserManagementService' while attempting to activate '.UserManagementController'.

Controller:-

```cs
public UserManagementController(IUserManagementService userManagementService)
{
    this._userManagementService = userManagementService;
    //this.applicationUser = applicationUser;
    //this.user = user;
}
```

service:-

```cs
public class UserManagementService : IUserManagementService { ... }
```

inprogram.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserManagementService, UserManagementService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserManagementRepoitory, UserManagementRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserManagementRepoitory, UserManagementRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserManagementService, UserManagementService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserManagementService, UserManagementService>();
```

I tried below in program.cs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserManagementService, UserManagementService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserManagementRepoitory, UserManagementRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserManagementRepoitory, UserManagementRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserManagementService, UserManagementService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserManagementService, UserManagementService>();
```

interface:-

```
public interface IUserManagementService { ... }
```